# Spacelike and timelike curves in de-Sitter space.

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, examples-counterexamples, general-relativity

I am working on space curves in Minkowski space and de-Sitter space. To
comprehend it better I am trying to come up with some examples of timelike
and spacelike curves.

A curve $x$ is locally spacelike if $\left\langle
x^{\prime },x^{\prime }\right\rangle >0$ and timelike if $\left\langle
x^{\prime },x^{\prime }\right\rangle <0.\ $de-Sitter 3-space can be defined
as $\mathbb{S}_{1}^{3}=\left\{ x\in \mathbb{R}_{1}^{4}:\left\langle
x,x\right\rangle =1\right\} ,~$where $\mathbb{R}_{1}^{4}$ is a Minkowski
space defined by a usual metric as $\left\langle x,y\right\rangle
=x_{1}y_{1}+x_{2}y_{2}+x_{3}y_{3}-x_{4}y_{4}.$

For example I find $x=\left(
\cos s,\sin s,1,1\right) $ as an example for a unit speed spacelike curve in
de-Sitter 3-space. It is in $\mathbb{S}_{1}^{3}$,~since $\left\langle
x,x\right\rangle =\cos ^{2}x+\sin ^{2}x+1-1=1~$and also it is spacelike
since $x^{\prime }=\left( -\sin s,\cos s,0,0\right) ~$and $\left\langle
x^{\prime },x^{\prime }\right\rangle =\sin ^{2}s+\cos ^{2}s=1>0.$ However I
could not find any example in de-sitter 3-space that is a unit speed
timelike.

Couple of my attemp failed as the following. I firstly thought
that $x=\left( \cosh s,0,0,\sinh s\right) ~$satisfy that it is in $\mathbb{S}%
_{1}^{3}$ and also $\left\langle x^{\prime },x^{\prime }\right\rangle <0\ $
however the curvature of this curve equals to zero  which I do not want this
either. Then I tried $x=\left( \cos s,\sin s,0,\sqrt{2}s\right) :~$this
satisfies $\left\langle x^{\prime },x^{\prime }\right\rangle <0$ however it
is not in $\mathbb{S}_{1}^{3},~$that is $\left\langle x,x\right\rangle \neq
1.$

Can you help me figure out with a good example?
I realized that my spacelike curve example has also zero curvature. So I failed on this one too. Curvature for spacelike and timelike curve can be found respectively by $\kappa =\left\Vert T^{\prime }+\alpha \right\Vert ,\ $
$\kappa =\left\Vert T^{\prime }-\alpha \right\Vert , $where $T$ is tangent of
the curve.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Considering that $\mathbb{S}^3_1$ is a sort of surface of revolution, I am pretty sure that some adaptation of Clairaut's relation applies (relation which expresses the fact that the 'angular momentum' is preserved along geodesics). Such a constant of motion would help to solve the geodesic equation (together with the velocity constraint), so that you could (in principle) determine every timelike geodesics. The curve $(\cosh s, 0, 0, \sinh s)$ is an example of a geodesic which is orthogonal to every latitude (i.e. constant time sphere).